# Avoid creating temporary files in Temp folder of Windows machine while executing automation using Robot Framework on Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, robotframework

I am executing my web application automation test cases in chrome browser using Robot Framework on Windows Machine. But, every time I execute the test suite, there will be temporary files created in the Temp folder.

So, I have total of 600 test cases and if I execute all of them at a stretch, There will be more than 10GB of temporary files will be created in the Temp folder which will halt my automation on some point saying the error:

> No disc space in the device

How can I avoid creating these temp files? Or is there code with will clear the temp folder every time I execute the test suite?

Comment: Are you sure the files are from Robot Framework (not from your tests steps)? Are they in subdir in Temp? What are the naming of the files?

Comment: Generally speaking, robot will not create any files anywhere unless you tell it to. What is in these files? Are they screenshots? log files? something else?

Comment: Whenever I execute the tests some random folders will get created in the Temp folder. I did not tried to open these folders but these are making my system hang all the time when i execute the test cases.

Comment: Again, you still have not clearly answer our questions. For example, if you run a single test suite 600 times, would you identify the temporary file increase? What are the libraries those test suites use? (we are not convinced that it is Robot Framework libraries causing those files)

Comment: I am using Selenium2Libary and chrome version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). Yes to your question, i tried launching another application, it created the temp folder. precisely for every application i open or run, it will create a temp file/folder. Now I am executing 600 text cases, means that many times my chrome will open with a default profile and i am executing this suite multiple time. Please let me know your thought on this.